# Is $\mu \in (0, 1]$ equivalent to the expression $\mu \in \{1,2, \ldots \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I understand $\mu \in   \{1,2,\ldots \}$ means $\mu$ is an element of the set $\{1,2,\ldots\}$.

Is it okay to interpret $\mu \in  (0, 1]$ in the same approach? What is the function of $($ and $]$ symbols in $(0, 1]$?

Comment: If [the Wikipedia article on *Interval*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)) is not helping you, then tell where the problems arise. Also, what do you mean by $R\{1,2,\ldots\}$? This seems to be no standard notation. For now: $\mu\in(0,1]$ can be interpreted as $0<\mu\le 1$.

Comment: I accidentally typed R while intended to type the dollar sign when I was  editing the initial post. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @M.Winter The wikipedia article is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(0,1] =\{ x: 0 < x \leq 1\}$$

$\mu$ is a postive real number  that is at most $1$.

Comment: One can also define $($ and $]$ on other sets than the real numbers though, but in general this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, the notation $(0,1]$ is *interval* notation.

It means the set of real numbers between $0$ and $1$, including $1$, but not including $0$.

Symbolically, $(0,1] = \{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid 0 < x \le 1\}$.

More generally, let $a,b$ be real numbers with $a < b$.

There are $4$ types of intervals from $a\;$to$\;b$, depending on whether the endpoints $a,b$ are both excluded, both included, or one is included but not the other. They are defined as follows . . .

- The open interval from $a\;$to$\;b$.
  - Interval notation: $(a,b)$.

    Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid a < x < b\}$

    Verbal description: The interval from $a$ to $b,\;$excluding both $a$ and $b$.

- The closed interval from $a\;$to$\;b$.
  - Interval notation: $[a,b]$.
  - Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid a \le x \le b\}$
  - Verbal description: The interval from $a\;$to$\;b,\;$including both $a$ and $b$.

- The interval from $a\;$to$\;b$, open on the left, closed on the right.
  - Interval notation: $(a,b]$.
  - Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid a < x \le b\}$
  - Verbal description: The interval from $a\;$to$\;b,\;$including $b$, but not including $a$.

- The interval from $a\;$to$\;b$, closed on the left, open on the right.
  - Interval notation: $[a,b)$.
  - Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid a \le x < b\}$
  - Verbal description: The interval from $a\;$to$\;b,\;$including $a$, but not including $b$.

In addition, there are unbounded intervals . . .

Let $c$ be a real number.

There are $4$ types of unbounded intervals having $c$ as an endpoint.

- The open interval from $-\infty\;$to$\;c$.
  - Interval notation: $(-\infty,c)$.

    Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x < c\}$

    Verbal description: The set of real numbers which are less than $c$.

- The interval from $-\infty\;$to$\;c$, closed on the right.
  - Interval notation: $(-\infty,c]$.

    Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x \le c\}$

    Verbal description: The set of real numbers which are less than or equal to $c$.

- The open interval from $c$ to $\infty$.
  - Interval notation: $(c,\infty)$.

    Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x > c\}$

    Verbal description: The set of real numbers which are greater than $c$.$\phantom{{Y_Y}_Y}$

- The interval from $c$ to $\infty$, closed on the left.
  - Interval notation: $[c,\infty)$.

    Set-builder notation: $\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid x \ge c\}$

    Verbal description: The set of real numbers which are greater than or equal to $c$.

Finally, there is one all-encompassing interval . . .

- The open interval from $-\infty\;$to$\;\infty$.
  - Interval notation: $(-\infty,\infty)$.

    Symbolic notation: $\mathbb{R}$.

    Verbal description: The set of all real numbers.